# Sqoop: When some nodes won't have direct JDBC access?

Tags: jdbc, mapreduce, sqoop

1) Im using the sqoop **import-all** command.

2) I have a scenario where I want do ETL from a **locally available sqoop source** into a **distributed** hadoop cluster... The machine that starts the ETL will have access to a JDBC source, but no gaurantee that all slaves on the cluster will have access to the JDBC source.

My questoin is:

Is there a way I can configure Sqoop to stream all the data from a single JDBC connection (possibly this means only using one mapper, but id like to instruct sqoop to do this, rather than do some mapreduce configuration hackery).

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine two options from top of my head:

1) Get a SQL proxy, install it on the node where you have guaranteed access to the database and use that proxy for Sqoop connections.

2) Run the Sqoop with Hadoop local mode and one mapper to ensure that the execution will never leave your computer. This options will be however very inefficient and therefore I would not recommend it for production use.

Answer (score 0):

You could control this by setting a [YARN Node Label](http://dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2-trunk/bk_system-admin-guide/content/configuring_node_labels.html) for the single server (with NodeManager running) which you wish to use to open the JDBC connection. Then when you run the Sqoop job, be sure to submit it to the [Capacity Scheduler Queue](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html) associated with that Node Label.

This should limit the JDBC connection to only the server which is marked with the YARN Node Label.